# Are more/other colors posible with other dimensions?

Tags: visible-light, spacetime-dimensions

<s>Like these [impossible colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossible_colors) (yellow/blue and green/red) or these [imaginary colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_color), for example saturated red more intense than pure spectral red can be viewed in ordinary viewing conditions.</s> Can other dimensions have different or extended visible spectrums?

Comment: As your link states color is in the eye of the beholder, so dimensions play no role. already there exists an electromagnetic spectrum invisible to our eye.

Comment: A color is nothing but the frequency of light (or a superposition of a bunch of frequencies). It exists completely independent of the number of dimensions. You have (essentially) the same theory of light in 1, 3 or 41 dimensions.

Comment: @Vibert that could be an answer

Comment: I could write about 7 critiques of this question, and only two would contain the word "qualia".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visible color spectrum depends on evolution and have nothing to do with dimensions. There are animals width different visible spectra than humans.

Comment: Does this mean that [impossible colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossible_colors) exist and can be viewed, just not generally by the human eye?

Comment: http://deserthighlandspr.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Visible-spectrum.jpg

Comment: What are you trying to point out?

Comment: just read this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light there is everithing you search for